# Block or limit unwanted traffic to Asp.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, security

I have a Asp.net 4.5 MVC web application intended for a small group of international users.  All functions available in the application are available to authenticated users only, there is no public content except for the login page.

For awhile I have had an error reporting system that emails me if an unhandled error occurs.  Some of these reports include requests for pages that are obvious bot based security scans looking for holes.  In an attempt to look at this problem further I installed an ip logging system that I could use to black list certain ip addresses (and store in a database table) and then use the Application_BeginRequest() method in the global.asax to return a 404 for a request from a blacklisted ip.

However, I recently deployed the routine and now see i am getting thousands of unwanted hits from thousands of different ip address scanning and looking for holes.  As part of this I record the requested url, one of the most common looks like the following:

/Account/SetCulture?culture=fr-FR&returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mellon-associates.com%2FUserProfile%2Ftabid%2F42%2FuserId%2F26403%2FDefault.aspx

There are many variations on the returnUrl parameter.  This doesn't work of course, as external urls are not supported by the application.

Regardless, I would greatly appreciate some suggestions on how I can lock down this application and the host server.  I would use a white list only approach as a last resort as I don't necessarily know what ip a user is coming from.

thanks, John

Comment: Wouldn't this be a job for a firewall?

Comment: possibly, how could the above be achieved via a firewall inbound rule?

Comment: beyond my knowledge I'm afraid - might be better posting on Information Security Exchange? Here's a topic I found as a starter: [link](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44931/difference-between-ids-and-ips-and-firewall)

Comment: I have my doubts I could do this via the firewall.  The types of rules I would need to employ are beyond the windows firewall capabilities.  Another post here suggested that the overhead of blocking this traffic wasn't worth the saved bandwidth. Still looking for solutions...

Answer (score 1):

You can use parts of IIS

1. "Request Filtering" for locking any parts in url.
2. "Dynamic IP Restrictions" for deny requests based on request frequency.
3. "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" for white/black lists of ip-addresses.