# HttpRequest Host Vulnerabilites

Tags: sql, security, httprequest, code-injection, host

I would like your advice regarding any security vulnerabilities from extracting the Domain Name from the Host property on an HttpRequest?

I have developed a PWA using ASP.NET Core that is multi-tenant and I extract the domain (i.e. The tenant) name from the host (HttpRequest.Host) which I use to look up information in a database.

For example, if I had a URL like [www.JoeBloggs.com](http://www.JoeBloggs.com) the extracted domain would be 'JoeBloggs'. Using this I then retrieve the information I require for that tenant.

Information is always sent over a HTTPS connection.

Can the Host value be faked or potentially used in a SQL Injection attack if I am using the domain name as part of a database lookup?

Thanks, Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Historically there have been a slew of [HTTP Host header attacks](https://portswigger.net/web-security/host-header) in which target webservers implicitly trust the `Host` header value with no/improper whitelist checking or sanitization. In short, it is possible to fake this value in certain contexts/configurations.

For concerns regarding SQL injection specifically, you should already be using prepared statements and parameterized queries to mitigate such risks; if you aren't already you should absolutely be working to refactor your SQL interaction code to do so. Even if the `Host` value sent by a malicious client is intended to exploit a SQL injection vulnerability somewhere downstream from the HTTP server, such a value shouldn't be able to trigger any unintended functionality or data exposure as parameters passed to query strings via mechanisms like prepared statements/parameterized queries wouldn't interpretable as SQL statements.

Relatedly, if you're using the value of the `Host` header to determine whether a client should receive any sort of "privileged" information in the response from your server - **don't**. A `Host` header value is not nearly a stand-in for a proper authentication/authorization flow and should absolutely never be used as such, considering it's able to be manipulated rather trivially. You can certainly use it in conjunction with other, more secure methods of authentication/authorization, but using it by itself is a big security no-no.

This advice does not preclude there being a separate exploitable flaw/bug in your database, database driver, or anywhere else in your stack that examines the contents of the `Host` header.